# angular mat-table сортировка и пагинатор не работают

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Решил сделать вот такую форму
[image: вот что должно получиться]

Все делаю как по гайду + нашел такой же компонент, но без кнопок.
И вроде бы ничего не отличается от предложенного, но у меня не работает, а там работает.
Сортировка должна быть только по названию

Прошу подсказать что я делаю не так.

**HTML**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Введите название изготовителя">
</mat-form-field>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="customers" matSort>
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id" hidden>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef hidden> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" hidden> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Название </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Address Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Адрес </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.address}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Phones Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phones">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Телефон </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phones}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Actions Column-->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Редактировать</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Удалить</button>
       </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>

<button mat-raised-button type="submit">Добавить изготовителя</button>
```

**TS**

```js
import { MatModule } from './../mat-module/mat-module.module';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomersClient, Customer } from 'src/app/api-service.service';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-customer',
  templateUrl: './list-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-customer.component.scss']
})
export class ListCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  customers = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'phones', 'actions'];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    new CustomersClient(httpClient).getCustomers().subscribe(response => {
      this.customers =  new MatTableDataSource(response);
    });
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customers.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.customers.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.customers.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

}
```

Comment: Alexandr а Вы импортировали `MatSortModule`  и `MatPaginatorModule` в ваш модуль?

Comment: если да пожалуйста убедитесь что в `ngOnInit` у вас `this.paginator` и `this.sort` не `undefined`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan они MatSort и MatPaginator соответственно. возможно я не туда их добавил... ListCustomerComponent это компонент у меня. мне `MatSortModule` и `MatPaginatorModule` где необходимо было прописать? я их в AppModule прописал

Comment: в компоненте все выглидит нормально. у вас ест SharedModule, где импортированы те модули которые нужно использовать в нескольких модулях?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan пока что всего 1 компонент, но вообще модуль с импортом angular-material есть. в нет также есть эти модули

Comment: ок. можете посмотреть что вивeдит это строка в консоле `console.log(this.paginator)`. пожалуйста поставьте эту строку в `ngOnInit` функцию

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan undefined вывело

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102886/discussion-between-ashot-aleqsanyan-and-alexandr).

Comment: @Alexandr во-первых твоя корневая причина в том, что ты асинхронно получаешь данные `getCustomers()` и создаешь новый инстанс `MatTableDataSource`, который ничего не знает о сортировщике и пагинаторе, сеттинг `sort` и `paginator` тебе нужно было просто перенести в `subscribe` метод. То, что оно у тебя равняется `undefined` в `ngOnInit` - это у тебя какое-то недетерменированное поведение, возможно ты просто привел не весь шаблон. Если этот подход, приведенный в документации материала, работает везде, но не работает у тебя - значит уже проблема на твоей стороне =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я думаю что вам нужно изменить ваш код следующим оброзам

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) set setPaginator(paginator: Paginator){

   this.customers.paginator = paginator; 
}

@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) set setSort(sort: MatSort){
    this.customers.sort = sort;
}

ngOnInit() {
}
```